# Loop till a specificData cannot found on List

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a class of list int thats compose of child and parentID ,use for identification .

```
 public class id
    {
        public int childID {get;set;}
        public int parentID {get;set;}
        public string text{get;set;}
    }
```

and I want a loop, base on currentID (currentChildID) that has a parentID .

e.g:

in my list (supposedly this is the data):

```
childID --- parentID --- text
  1            0         aaa
  2            1         bbb
  3            2         ccc
  4            2         ddd
```

and supposedly my currentID was 1 so what I wanted was to get all childID that has parentID value of 1 .

in the sample above its 2 .

then create a condition inside getting text of 2 (which is bbb) .

then after this loop verify if theres data in list that has parentID of 2

so in sample above its 3 and 4 ...

then if theres no parentID value containing a number e.g: 3 and 4 loop will end .

so its a continous looping till the childID value has no parentID value on the list ...

edit:

i haven't try any so far related with looping, except for completing data needed on list , but i guess its something like:

```
int theCurrentID = 0;
bool initial = idList.Any(n => n.currentID == childID);
if (initial)
{
//loop and gettext
foreach(var x in idList.Where(n => n.currentID == childID))
{

    theCurrentID = x.childID; //supposedly currentID
}

bool next = idList.Any(n => theCurrentID == parentID);
//loop and gettext
if (next)
{
    foreach(var x in idList.Where(n => theCurrentID == parentID)
    {


    }
}
else
{
//parent not found
}
```

Note: this sample stops on second loop and dont verify if theres still parentID .

Comment: Another 'use magic ball to predict the problem' question?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @nvoigt, i have updated the q . i haven't try any so far, except for completing data needed on list

Comment: You should have at least tried yourself...

Comment: Try 10 times and when you give up - then create question. That is purpose of Stackoverflow project, not create program for me.

Comment: @Reniuz, i already tried, thought its not 10times, but its the best i can ...

Comment: Can you specify clear problem? You dont know how to stop when you cant find parentID?

Comment: @Reniuz no ... i dont know how to do continuous looping when you dont know how many more loops till current childID has no parentID ...

Comment: I'm confused about all that parentID, childID and looping talk. Can you put into a plain english sentence what it is that you want? You have a node and now you want what exactly?

Comment: Where is the Close Bracket `)` in this line `foreach(var x in idList.Where(n => n.currentID == childID)` for foreach.

Comment: What if you have item with 1,2 and 4 parent id? You need to stop on 3 because it doesnt have any records with parentid == 3?

Comment: @Reniuz yeah it will stop till parentID not found ...

Comment: @Shell, already added thanks for mentioning

Comment: And your idList is ordered by clildID?

Comment: @nvoigt, i already tried my best to explain sorry if its a bit confusing ... but i still try to think of a sample to pin what i really want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one way to go for this is recursive function:

```
private void Traverse(int childID, List<id> data)
    {
        //Pre-action:: Top to bottom approach, to work on items from top level
        //data.Where(x => x.childID == childID);

        foreach (var child in data.Where(x => x.parentID == childID))
        {
            Traverse(child.childID, data);
        }

        //Post-action:: Bottom to top approach, to work on items from root level
        //data.Where(x => x.childID == childID);
    }
```

Use this function as:

```
int theCurrentID = 1;
List<id> temp = new List<id>();
temp.Add(new id() { childID = 1, parentID = 0, text = "1" });
temp.Add(new id() { childID = 2, parentID = 1, text = "2" });
temp.Add(new id() { childID = 3, parentID = 2, text = "3" });
temp.Add(new id() { childID = 4, parentID = 3, text = "4" });

Traverse(theCurrentID, temp);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1st glance and it gives me the idea of what I needed . thanks . :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll try to help you but I'am still not 100% sure what you expecting :)

First rename `childID` to `ID` and name of class because it is very confusing.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int parentID {get;set;}
    public string text{get;set;}
}

//loop through all items
foreach(var currentItem in idList.OrderBy(x=>x.ID))
{
  //get a list of parent items 
  List<id> parents = idList.Where(x=>x.parentID == currentItem.ID);

  if(parents.Count == 0)
  {
     //we dont have any records which parentID is current item ID so stop executing loop further
     break;
  }

  //Here you loop through all parents and do what you want
  foreach(var parentItem in parents)
  {
     //Do what you want with parentItem
  }
}
```

P.s. code not tested